# Matching column values with elements in a list of lists of lists and adding corresponding values from another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
assets = [[['Ferrari', 'BMW', 'Suzuki'], ['Ducati', 'Honda']], [['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Oppo']]]
price = [[[853600, 462300, 118900], [96500, 16700]], [[1260, 750, 340]]]
```

I have a dataframe as follows :

| Car | Bike | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | Ducati | Apple |
| Ferrari | Honda | Oppo |

Looking for code to get the Total_Cost , i.e 462300 + 96500 + 1260 = 560060

| Car | Bike | Phone | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | Ducati | Apple | 560060 |
| Ferrari | Honda | Oppo | 870640 |

I tried the for loop and succeeded, I want the advanced code if any.

Comment: Provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you sure that `... [['Ferrari', 'BMW', 'Suzuki'], ['Ducati', 'Honda']] ...`  isn't `... [['Ferrari', 'BMW', 'Suzuki']], [['Ducati', 'Honda']] ...` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': ['BMW', 'Ferrari'], 'Bike': ['Ducati', 'Honda'], 'Phone': ['Apple', 'Oppo']})

asset_price = {asset: price[a][b][c] 
                for a, asset_list in enumerate(assets) 
                for b, asset_sub_list in enumerate(asset_list) 
                for c, asset in enumerate(asset_sub_list)
}

df['Total_Cost'] = df.apply(lambda row: sum([asset_price[asset] for asset in row]), axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
       Car    Bike  Phone  Total_Cost
0      BMW  Ducati  Apple      560060
1  Ferrari   Honda   Oppo      870640
```

You can also use numpy approach `import numpy as np` depending on your use-case. But I will suggest the first approach which is more simple and easy to understand.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': ['BMW', 'Ferrari'], 'Bike': ['Ducati', 'Honda'], 'Phone': ['Apple', 'Oppo']})

flat_assets = np.concatenate([np.concatenate(row) for row in assets])
flat_price = np.concatenate([np.concatenate(row) for row in price])

asset_dict = dict(zip(flat_assets, flat_price))
asset_prices = np.array([asset_dict[row] for row in df.values.flatten() 
                            if row in asset_dict])

df['Total Cost'] = np.sum(asset_prices.reshape(-1, 3), axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
       Car    Bike  Phone  Total Cost
0      BMW  Ducati  Apple      560060
1  Ferrari   Honda   Oppo      870640
```

Comment: Thanks Timus. But if the nested lists of asset is having common name (say : Honda in place if Suzuki ) then Honda car and Honda Bike will take one price.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

First build a dataframe `df_price` which maps `price`s onto the `assets` and the classification (`Car`, `Bike`, and `Phone`):

```py
df_price = (
    pd.DataFrame({"assets": assets, "price": price}).explode(["assets", "price"])
    .assign(cols=["Car", "Bike", "Phone"]).explode(["assets", "price"])
)
```

Result:

```
    assets   price   cols
0  Ferrari  853600    Car
0      BMW  462300    Car
0   Suzuki  118900    Car
0   Ducati   96500   Bike
0    Honda   16700   Bike
1    Apple    1260  Phone
1  Samsung     750  Phone
1     Oppo     340  Phone
```

(I have inserted the classification here due to the comment on the other answer: *"... But if the nested lists of asset is having common name (say : Honda in place if Suzuki ) then Honda car and Honda Bike will take one price"*.

Then join the prices onto the `.melt`ed main dataframe `df`, `.pivot` (using the auxilliary column `idx`), sum up the prices in the rows, and bring the result in shape.

```py
res = (
    df.melt(var_name="cols", value_name="assets", ignore_index=False)
    .merge(df_price, on=["cols", "assets"])
    .assign(idx=lambda df: df.groupby("cols").cumcount())
    .pivot(index="idx", columns="cols")
    .assign(total=lambda df: df.loc[:, "price"].sum(axis=1))
    .loc[:, ["assets", "total"]]
    .droplevel(0, axis=1).rename(columns={"": "Total_Costs"})
)
```

Result:

```
cols    Bike      Car  Phone  Total_Costs
idx                                      
0     Ducati      BMW  Apple     560060.0
1      Honda  Ferrari   Oppo     870640.0
```